# wxBusyCursor not showing on a modal dialog

Tags: windows, cursor, wxwidgets

I got this in latest version of wxWidgets (3.1) while in 3.0.1 it was working as expected.

On Mac, this problems appears if the model window is disabled, on Windows (I tryed Win8) it does not matter, it is there in both cases.

If dialog is not modal, then the issue is gone, but I need this dialog model.

Anyone had the same issue, any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks like a bug, if you can provide a simple way to reproduce it (e.g. by making the smallest possible patch to the [dialogs sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/samples/dialogs/dialogs.cpp)), you should open a ticket in [wxWidgets bug tracker](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the replay, that is what I thought, but I was hoping it will not be the answer. I will file a report soon.